# Multiple cell selection in DataGrid Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I'm using a DataGrid object to diplay data in a table. Is there a way to allow multiple cell selection with DataGrid? I've seen it's posible with AdvancedDataGrid but I want to keep this as a last resort solution to my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're out of luck; as the MX DataGrid doesn't support multiple cell selection--although you can select multiple rows with the allowMultipleSelection property.  I thought it was possible to do column selection with the Spark DataGrid if you can upgrade your SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting **allowMultipleSelection** to true. Please note that in order to select multiple rows you need to hold down the control key.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it as follows ,

```
<mx:DataGrid id="xyz" allowMultipleSelection="true" />
```